# Doing validation in stored procedure if data already exist

Tags: sql-server-2005

I want to create a stored procedure where I want to check if I add a `Bin no` and if exist in the table it should give me *validation message* otherwise it should work

I tried like below but it is not working

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_P_WMS_Stock_Adj_Val_Proc]
    (@Bin_no nvarchar(max)) 
AS BEGIN
    IF (@Bin_no = )
    BEGIN
          RAISERROR('Bin no already exist', 16, 1)
          RETURN
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT DISTINCT 
            Location_Name + '-' +  convert(varchar, mkey) 
        FROM
            WMS_Storage_Bin 
        WHERE
            status = 'Confirmed' 
            AND location_name = @Bin_no
    END 
END
```

I am using SQL Server 2005.

Comment: use a unique constraint ......rather than a trigger

Comment: @MitchWheat: can you suggest how to use that? as I not that familiar with it. sorry for this

Comment: I'd start by typing "sql server unique constraint ." into a search engine...

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: @marc_s: i would not use that pefix only. Any idea about validation in `Storedprocedure` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really **must** do this in a stored procedure - then use this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.ValidateWMSStock
    (@Bin_no nvarchar(max)) 
AS BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.WMS_Storage_Bin 
               WHERE location_name = @Bin_no)
    BEGIN
          RAISERROR('Bin no already exist', 16, 1)
          RETURN
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT DISTINCT 
            Location_Name + '-' +  convert(varchar, mkey) 
        FROM
            WMS_Storage_Bin 
        WHERE
            status = 'Confirmed' 
            AND location_name = @Bin_no
    END 
END
```

But as Mitch Wheat already said - it's probably much easier to just put a **unique constraint** on that column:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.WMS_Storage_Bin
   ADD CONSTRAINT UQ_Location_Name UNIQUE(location_name)
```

Once the unique constraint is in place, if you attempt to insert a row with a `location_name` that already exists, you'll get an error

> Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Line xx
>   Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'UQ_Location_Name'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.WMS_Storage_Bin'. The duplicate key value is (......).

**Update:**

I tried this - I believe the code I provided works **just fine**:

```
DECLARE @BinTable TABLE (ID INT NOT NULL, Location_Name NVARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO @BinTable VALUES(1, N'A1112'), (2, N'A1113'), (3, N'A1114'), (4, N'A1121')

DECLARE @Bin_No NVARCHAR(MAX)

-- SET @Bin_No = N'A1112'  -- this prints "Bin already exists" as expected
SET @Bin_No = N'A4112'     -- this prints "Bin does *NOT* exist" as expected

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @BinTable WHERE location_name = @Bin_no)
    PRINT 'Bin already exists'
ELSE
    PRINT 'Bin does *NOT* exist'
```

Comment: I have one bin still it is giving me the error as `bin not exist` I tried **IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.WMS_Storage_Bin 
               WHERE location_name <> @Bin_no)** still not working

Comment: What's the datatype of `location_name` in your table??

Comment: the datatype is `nvarchar`

Comment: Then please show some sample data - what is already in the table? What are you trying to insert?

Comment: I guess the code, is `IF EXIST` then throw error, but what i want is, if it does not exist then throw the error

Comment: I added that error thing in else part and it worked. thanks marc_s

Comment: @coder: if you want to do something if the value does **not** exist, then use `IF NOT EXISTS ( ..... )` (instead of the `IF EXISTS (...)`)

Comment: yes, actually I gaved it a try by thinking what my requirement is. And In first attempt it worked for me. Once again thanks a lot :)